# Three responsive Adsense units in a page without breaking similar ad sizes policy

Tags: google-adsense, responsive-webdesign, google-adsense-policies

If I put three responsive ad units, will they comply with the policies?

e.g. in a case where it might be possible for Google to serve 3 300x600 units for responsive ad units on page, it would only serve 300x600 once, and the other two will be 300x250.

> Publishers may not place more than one "large" ad unit per page. We 
>   define a "large" ad unit as any unit similar in size to our 300x600 
>   format. For example, this would include our 300x1050 and 970x250 
>   formats, our 750x200 and 580x400 regional formats, and any other
>   custom  sized ad with comparable dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

> ...it would only serve 300x600 once, and the other two will be 300x250.

It's generally not a good idea to define ads at these sizes, especially if your ads are located "above the fold", meaning in the section of the page a user can see before scrolling. Additionally, you will need to have a lot of content on your page to even qualify for such setup and have the ads spaced apart from each other nicely and not have one right next to another. It's not a great idea to have an ad push content down the page, especially if what users see are ads to start, requiring them to scroll to see content.

Also, take this into consideration. My screen resolution is 800x600 and any of your ads will take up just over 1/3 of my screen width and an ad will take up either my entire screen height or almost 1/2 my screen height. Putting all three ads above the fold and making the site public will cause me to wonder what kind of site I landed on.

I suggest using Google analytics or some other internet software that collects the screen width and height of all devices that connect to your website and determine ad sizes based on the lowest screen resolution.

Also, if the amount of content you have is too little, then go with just only one ad unit, not three.

And as per google's terms, only use responsive ad units if your site is 100% responsive (meaning the same URL can be browsed nicely on a phone and on a standard computer).

Comment: May be my question was not clear enough, I was referring to the ads generated by Google responsive ad unit https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en where it automatically generates them, the question is if those generated ads can break rules or Google generate those three units to fit the allowed sizes.

Comment: I read the link and it states `There are some situations in which you’ll need to take extra action to make a responsive ad unit work correctly:`.... `The parent container has no width set. If you place your responsive ad code within a parent container that doesn’t have an explicit width set, for example, within a floating element, then our ad code won’t be able to calculate the required size for the responsive ad unit.`. This tells me some kind of measurement needs to be explicitly set for the ad to display. I wonder if their responsive units work...

Answer (score 0):

From the definition you provided it sounds like that would be fine. I don't think the 300x250 ads would count as "large" ads according to their definition.

Comment: It was just an example, I was referring to the ads generated by Google when you use their responsive ad units, where it generates them automatically.